# Can I run 2x's 200 amp services off of my 200 amp meter?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I have a 200 amp service in my house from the pole that is live. My polebarn is about 150 ft. Away from the pole and is not live. I have another 200 amp service for my polebarn, and I have the extra slots under my meter to hook another service up there. I know I'll need at least 150ft of 1/0 aluminum direct burial as well. Or should I scrap the other 200 amp box (buddy gave it to me) get a 100 amp box, and run it as a sub service from the house?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When you  say "I have another 200 amp service for my polebarn", you mean you have a 200-amp-capable breaker box that you're thinking of installing?

Comment: Can you post photos of the breaker box at the pole please?

Comment: Don't rush off and buy wire yet. However you arrived at 1/0 for your wire size is quite wrong.

Comment: Daniel griscom: that is exactly what I mean. Threephaseeel: I can tomorrow. Harper: I won't be buying the cable for at least 2 weeks.